# What are True,False and NULL in R functions and How can I character be converted To it?

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I am writing a shiny app and some options in function are NULL, TRUE and FALSE

example:

```
Dimplot(object, label = True, Repel = False, cols = NULL)
```

How can I make sure that character is converted to NULL or False from text input. I am using right now a series of if, else if but find so many combinations is tedious is there a simple so

```
Dimplot(object, label = True, Repel = input$repel, cols = NULL)
```

works for me.

Comment: There are some widgets, shown here https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/widget-gallery.html, that will return TRUE or FALSE. For instance, see `checkboxInput()`.

Comment: Regarding the handling of NULL, you'll need to be a bit more specific in terms of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: As @Phil said, best would be to use the appropriate input that returns TRUE/FALSE, like a checkbox. In addition, I would read that input as a factor, automatically rejecting those inputs that are not defined in the factor. As for NULL, I would use NA.